# How to store pancakes

Tags: storage-method, pancakes

Can I just put a stack in the freezer, with some paper between each? Do I need to make any changes to my ingredients (Milk, Flour, Butter, Sugar, Salt, Eggs) for efficient storage?

When I reheat them in the pan, will they regain the same texture?

Comment: Ok...no eggs or leavening?

Comment: no leavening. eggs edited

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pancakes behave like high-fat bread. They go stale rather quickly.

Your recipe doesn't need to be altered.

Let them cool completely so you don't freeze condensation. Wrap them tightly to keep out air. If you really care about them you can use the paper between layers but I haven't found it to be necessary. If they freeze together they can be easily pried apart.

I have never tried recooking them in the pan so I can't speak to how well that would work. I reheat mine either in the microwave or toaster depending on how much time I have. The texture is not exactly the same as fresh but not worse, just different.

Comment: okay my pancakes froze quite well in plastic, no freezer burns. they reheated quite well in the pan, although the sides turned out to be crispier than desired.